# Лучшая практика по созданию универсального компонента таблицы

Tags: html, css, reactjs, веб-программирование

Как лучше создать UI Table элемент? Через теги div или table? Не могу определиться, что лучше и есть ли какая-то разница?

Comment: Раньше всё что надо и не надо верстали через таблицы, потому что легко их было позиционировать. С момента как появился html5 всё остальное можно сверстать дивами или какими угодно ещё блочными элементами. Если вам нужна именно таблица (табличные данные, строчки, колонки, возможность сортировки и всё прочее) - так и верстайте таблицу.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо!